# Shell script finally block

Tags: bash, shell, docker-compose

I have a shell script where i have 3 commands. I want to execute the second command if the first one is successful, which can be done using `command1` && `command2` and if any error occurs, I want to `command2` to exit with non zero code. I also would like to execute `command3` in any case when `command2` is a success or a failure.

Till now have done this:

```
#!/bin/bash

(command1 && command2)

command3
```

`Command2` is a docker compose up command that  do not want to execute in detach mode.

How can this be done?

Comment: You can capture return code using `$?` and execute command in `if-else` block

Comment: can you try this one   command1 && command2 | command3

Comment: @EatPayBong : In addition to the obvious solution suggested by DigvijayS, you have to think what the overall exit code should be if `command2` returns exit code 0, but `command1` and/or `command3` have non-zero exit code.

Comment: @Taybur Rahaman: You for sure mean `||` and not `|`. But in this case, `command3` would not be executed if both `command1` and `command2` succeed.

Comment: @user1934428 you are correct, i meant ||,

Comment: Properly indent the code and adjust lexical & grammar issues

Answer (score 0):

To run a command after another no matter which exit code returns, try:

```
command1 && command2 ; command3
```

Another way, keeping in mind that you want to retrieve a non-zero exit code on `command2` failure but still keep the script going:

```
#!/bin/bash

set +e

command1

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  command2 2>&1 || echo "command2 failed with $? exit code"
fi

command3
```

Comment: Your suggestion does not guarantee a non-zero exit code of the script, if command2 fails.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, I did not take into account that specific condition at all the first time I read the question.

Answer (score 0):

hads0m is on the right track.

```
#!/bin/bash

set +e

command1
result=$?
if [ $result -eq 0 ]; then
  command2
fi

command3
if [ $result -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "command1 failed." >&2
  exit $result
fi
```